# How to provide PATH to a jEdit commando?

Tags: node.js, path, jedit

After installing

1. [node.js](http://gist.github.com/579814),
2. `npm`,
3. the [latest jEdit for Ubuntu](http://jedit.org/index.php?page=download#option_two),
4. the jEdit Console plugin, and
5. a [CoffeeScript commando](http://community.jedit.org/?q=node/view/4968) (sic!),

and then configuring the `coffee` path in `coffee.xml`, it won't run because `node` is not found:

```
/home/user/local/bin/coffee -c foo.js.coffee
Process /home/user/local/bin/coffee exited with code 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

This is most likely because `/home/user/local/bin` is missing from the `PATH` by the time the Console plugin tries to run `coffee`. Is there some way to provide this environment variable without modifying `/home/user/local/bin/coffee`?

Tried to set Plugins → Console → System Shell → Subshell extra PATH to `/home/user/local/bin`, but it didn't take.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a bug in jEdit / Console. I saved the "Subshell extra PATH" option, closed the dialog, ran `coffee` and got the same results, checked the options again, and gave up. Restarted jEdit, and found that the option had been *removed*. Entered it again, and now `coffee` ran fine. For anyone else who runs into this issue:

1. Install everything.
2. **Restart jEdit.**
3. **Set the "Subshell extra PATH" option.**
4. Profit!